# Application Details on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want to develop an application which gets the details of other installed applications on Blackberry.  Is there any possibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [CodeModuleGroupManager.loadAll()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/CodeModuleGroupManager.html#loadAll%28%29) to get a list of all applications installed on the device.

Comment: i got all details but can't find application size
So, How can i find application size.