# how to find application size in blackberry by code?

Tags: blackberry

i want to know how to find application size in blackberry by code?
I want to display application name which are running along with its size on click of button, so how should i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave some explanation please see this  link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9074486/914111

Answer (score -1):

Here the answer of your question.
You will get your answer with this link.

[app details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874315/application-details-on-blackberry)

```
public class readjad extends FullScreen{
public readjad() {
      VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(VERTICAL_SCROLL);
        ApplicationDescriptor desc = ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor();
        CodeModuleGroup[] group = CodeModuleGroupManager.loadAll();
        if(group != null) {
            for( int i=0;i<CodeModuleGroupManager.getNumberOfGroups();i++) {
                Enumeration e = group[i].getPropertyNames();
                e.hasMoreElements();
                vfm.add(new RichTextField("\n\nGroup: " + group[i].getName() ));
                String name = (String)e.nextElement();
                vfm.add(new RichTextField(name + ": " + group[i].getProperty(name)));
                vfm.add(new RichTextField("Copyright" + ": " + group[i].getCopyright()));
                vfm.add(new RichTextField("Vendor" + ": " + group[i].getVendor()));
            }
        } else {
            vfm.add(new RichTextField("Group is null"));
        }
       add(vfm);
    }
}
```

Comment: will you tell me how to do it exactly i m totally new to BB? one example to show it by click on button...........please

Comment: it shows me "Group is null". Actually i already got application name which are running but i want their memory size also ....this application shows me group is null why it is like this?

Comment: This code will give the full details of the applications but it can't give the size of the application.
Sorry.

Comment: ok .bt also thanks, do you have any idea about that then please tell me .