# How to find running application size programatically in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, filesize

i want to find the size of running application of blackberry by code.I checked the [how to find application size in blackberry by code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845088/how-to-find-application-size-in-blackberry-by-code) link but i am not getting answer. Please suggest me solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi can you please provide me some more details that Size of running application of blackberry means total size of all cod files?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean of **size of running application**   that **size of total cod files** 
then we can calculate.

when we instal application using JAD we can see the application size.

For example: my application name is **PictureBackground**

After successful sign in application we can take cod fils and jad file for devise installation. when we click on PictureBackground.jad then we can find following type of information

**Name:**    PictureBackground

**Version:** 1.0.0

**Vender:**  Blackberry Developer

**Size:**   513.4kb

If you want to pragmatically retrieve that size, then we can do it as following

we can find all information about application in PictureBackground.jad file

For example PictureBackground.jad file as follow:

```
RIM-COD-SHA1-4: ff 3c 2f ec 7b 6a 3d 1a e3 86 ec d2 87 0a c3 e1 6c f3 14 0e
RIM-COD-SHA1-3: 07 4d f7 db 9a f3 df 1d 00 90 b6 4f 54 f0 3a f0 c8 de ca b1
RIM-COD-SHA1-2: 95 14 4a 6a 7d 3a 1b db 2e 0f 05 b8 e1 ff 66 8a e0 ce f1 64
RIM-COD-SHA1-1: 68 a7 09 4e dc cf 2f c1 9b 43 d1 0b 35 b8 4b bc 35 72 ba 92
RIM-MIDlet-Flags-1: 0
MIDlet-Jar-Size: 591513
MIDlet-Name: PictureBackground
MIDlet-Jar-URL: PictureBackground.jar
MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.1
RIM-COD-URL-9: PictureBackground-9.cod
RIM-COD-URL-8: PictureBackground-8.cod
RIM-COD-URL-7: PictureBackground-7.cod
RIM-COD-Module-Dependencies: net_rim_cldc
RIM-COD-URL-6: PictureBackground-6.cod
RIM-COD-URL-5: PictureBackground-5.cod
RIM-COD-URL-4: PictureBackground-4.cod
RIM-COD-URL-3: PictureBackground-3.cod
RIM-COD-URL-2: PictureBackground-2.cod
RIM-COD-URL-1: PictureBackground-1.cod
RIM-COD-Size-9: 51288
RIM-COD-Size-8: 55284
RIM-COD-Size-7: 58560
RIM-COD-Size-6: 51340
RIM-COD-Size-5: 55748
RIM-COD-Size-4: 53000
RIM-COD-Size-3: 55084
RIM-COD-Module-Name: PictureBackground
RIM-COD-Size-2: 51284
RIM-COD-Size-1: 60448
RIM-COD-SHA1: 55 82 db c2 8c 44 73 c8 44 b6 ce 7f 20 bb 70 47 d2 df fe ab
RIM-COD-Size: 33688
MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.0
MIDlet-Vendor: BlackBerry Developer
MIDlet-1: PictureBackground,,
RIM-COD-URL: PictureBackground.cod
Manifest-Version: 1.0
MIDlet-Version: 1.0.0
RIM-COD-SHA1-9: 76 04 75 59 21 27 c6 18 97 ed 49 fb ce 03 f3 21 fd 63 c1 96
RIM-COD-SHA1-8: 79 a9 b7 85 59 aa 06 e6 4b 76 89 de 12 cd 10 0d 54 93 48 dd
RIM-COD-SHA1-7: 3d d1 d1 47 e3 8d b5 9d 57 89 51 e3 a9 b3 77 5e c4 57 17 a8
RIM-COD-Creation-Time: 1327931490
RIM-COD-SHA1-6: f7 78 f7 b3 46 f5 69 91 9d 87 33 d0 a9 9d 9b 92 b6 de 90 74
RIM-COD-SHA1-5: 98 b3 45 64 8b 5f 36 0a aa c1 0e 2e 66 ea 7a f7 50 37 05 7a
```

**Through this we can find the running application size**
 **Sample code :**

```
 package samplecode;

import java.util.Enumeration;

import net.rim.device.api.system.ApplicationDescriptor;
import net.rim.device.api.system.CodeModuleGroup;
import net.rim.device.api.system.CodeModuleGroupManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public class StartUp extends UiApplication{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StartUp up=new StartUp();
        up.enterEventDispatcher();
    }
    public StartUp()
    {
        MainScreen screen=new MainScreen();
         CodeModuleGroup cmg = null;
            CodeModuleGroup[] allGroups = CodeModuleGroupManager.loadAll();
            String moduleName = ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor().getModuleName();
            for (int i = 0; i < allGroups.length; i++) {
               if (allGroups[i].containsModule(moduleName)) {
                   cmg = allGroups[i];
                  break;
                 }
            }
            if (cmg == null) {
                screen.add(new LabelField("not able to fetch properties"));
            } else {
                double size=0;
                for (Enumeration e = cmg.getPropertyNames(); e
                        .hasMoreElements();) {
                    String name = (String) e.nextElement();
                    String value = cmg.getProperty(name);

                    if(name.indexOf("RIM-COD-Size")!=-1)
                    {
                        size=size+Double.parseDouble(value);
                    }
                    //add(new LabelField("Name: " + name));

                }
                screen.add(new LabelField("Size: " +(size/1024)+"kb"));
            }
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(screen);

    }

}
```

**NOTE: IT WONT WORK ON SIMULATOR, IT WORKS ON DEVISE(IT SHOULD BE INSTALL FROM JAD FILE) AND WE CAN FIND OUTPUT AS FOLLOWING**

```
size:513.40234375KB
```