# How to get JAD file information in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I want all the information associated with jad files in blackberry.how should i get it?

Comment: you need to show some effort then you can ask

Answer (score 1):

try the following code please note that

> **this is work on Device only dont test on emulator**

```
import java.util.Enumeration;

import net.rim.device.api.system.ApplicationDescriptor;
import net.rim.device.api.system.CodeModuleGroup;
import net.rim.device.api.system.CodeModuleGroupManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public class StartUp extends UiApplication{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StartUp up=new StartUp();
        up.enterEventDispatcher();
    }
    public StartUp()
    {
        MainScreen screen=new MainScreen();
         CodeModuleGroup cmg = null;
            CodeModuleGroup[] allGroups = CodeModuleGroupManager.loadAll();
            String moduleName = ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor().getModuleName();
            for (int i = 0; i < allGroups.length; i++) {
               if (allGroups[i].containsModule(moduleName)) {
                   cmg = allGroups[i];
                  break;
                 }
            }
            if (cmg == null) {
                screen.add(new LabelField("not able to fetch properties"));
            } else {
                double size=0;
                for (Enumeration e = cmg.getPropertyNames(); e
                        .hasMoreElements();) {
                    String name = (String) e.nextElement();
                    String value = cmg.getProperty(name);
                    System.out.println(name+" : "+value);
                    screen.add(new LabelField(name+" : "+value,Field.FOCUSABLE));
                }
            }
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(screen);

    }

}
```

Comment: cmg is always returning null so unable to retrieve properties

Comment: did you test on device or simulator?you should test on device only

Comment: I want to know information related to COD files.i.e.how many COD files are there in JAD file and their sizes.so how is it possible?

Comment: before asking question you need to know your requirement exactly then ask. because you are asking about JAD information so i post that.you want code size and code file information then i already gave answer here see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9074486/914111 and accept my answer as your answer

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for providing me such a useful information but if i want to develop 1 application which should retrieve same information i.e COD file sizes of all running application then will it be possible?if yes then please post the code about it